# Automated mobile testing strategy for the usecases that involves multiple phones - say bluetooth data transfer, etc

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, automated-tests, android-testing

What could be the best automation test strategy for mobile uses cases that involve multiple devices:

- Bluetooth data transfer
- Push data from one phone and pull the same from other phone
- Hit like or share button on one phone and see the count updated on the other phone
- Send SMS from one phone and check if the SMS is received on other phone

The usecase can involve multiple platforms too (*iOS to iOS / android to android / iOS to android / android to iOS*)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two Appium instances, each associated with one device and executed the test case. It was successful and did solve my problem. However, I am not sure if this is the best approach.